Death in the saddle
Is it ok to characterize someone's death as "in the saddle" if he died (naturally, after a long and adventurous life) in the course of a military campaign, without having necessarily been killed in action? I'd usually defer to google on this, but it's swamped with references to some TV show.

Many thanks for the sensible advice, also the google pointer. Yes I'm a bit worried about the euphemism too; the cliché aspect is less bad in this case. But I'll think about it (and check out the obit you mention in the meantime!)

“*There are various euphemisms for death during sex, including "dying in the saddle" or the French "la mort d'amour". *”https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Death_during_consensual_sex#:~:text=Death%20can%20occur%20during%20sexual,la%20mort%20d'amour%22.

Any reason to prefer this to the phrase "died in harness"? Both are old-fashioned, but "died in the saddle" was never anywhere near as popular as "died in harness" was at its most popular.

“In the saddle” is from the years of popularity of Westerns in U.S. programming. It certainly implies “at work.” Was it ever really military, except in the days of cavalry?

It's a bit of a cliché, so for that reason alone I'd avoid it (except as the title of a TV show, for example).  It is also used as a euphemism for "death during sex".  You might provoke some sniggers.
More generally, it is nearly always used figuratively, to mean "died doing something, (rather than in bed).  and doesn't particularly refer to death from enemy action. A fisherman who dies at sea might be said to have "died in the saddle" in this figurative sense.
For your google-fu  try searching "Death in the saddle" -bones  to filter out references to the show.

As expected, ngram has zero hits for "she died in the saddle".

THere's an obitury of Jane Russell in which she is described as having died in the saddle (in the non-sex sense)

My favorite line from that obit: To contain her ample bust the designer of the "Spruce Goose" airplane used his engineering skills to make Russell a special push-up bra.

"died doing something, (rather than in bed)"... I mean, those aren't necessarily mutually exclusive

@NoName {snigger}
